# VSCode: Is it possible to suppress ts(1136) warnings in javascript decorator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, decorator

I use decorator in VUE project, like this:

```js
methods: {
  @debounce(500)
  resizeInstant () {
    // do something
  },
}
```

In VSCode, I get this warning in `.vue` file:

> Property assignment expected. vetur(1136)

and get this warining in `.js` file:

> Property assignment expected. ts(1136)

I can add `"vetur.validation.script": false` and `"javascript.validate.enable": false,`  to my `settings.json` file to remove `vetur(1136)` and `ts(1136)` warnings. The ramifications is that VSCode's built in code syntax checking doesn't run. I want to know if there are other better practices to suppress this warning?

Comment: did you try  // @ts-ignore ? above the line you want to suppress

Comment: I just tried it，`// @ts-ignore` can't suppress it.

Comment: Vetur error messages are annoying, I just replaced with another extension